# with pyspark.sql.functions unix_timestamp get null

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, unix-timestamp

I try to convert a column from string to timestamp with this code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
(sc
.parallelize([Row(dt='2017-01-23T08:12:39.929+01:00')])
.toDF()
.withColumn("parsed", unix_timestamp("dt", "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
.cast("double")
.cast("timestamp"))
.show(1, False))
```

but I get null

```
+-----------------------------+------+
|dt                           |parsed|
+-----------------------------+------+
|2017-01-23T08:12:39.929+01:00|null  |
+-----------------------------+------+
```

why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get `NULL` because format you use doesn't match the data. To get a minimal match you'll have to escape `T` with single quotes:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss
```

and to match the full pattern you'll need `S` for millisecond and `X` for timezone:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

but in the current Spark version direct `cast`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

col("dt").cast("timestamp")
```

should work just fine:

```
spark.sql(
    """SELECT CAST("2011-01-23T08:12:39.929+01:00" AS timestamp)"""
).show(1, False)
```

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|CAST(2011-01-23T08:12:39.929+01:00 AS TIMESTAMP)|
+------------------------------------------------+
|2011-01-23 08:12:39.929                         |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Reference: [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).